# How to automate process of starting app inside docker container

Tags: bash, docker, flask, automation

I am working on an Flask REST API developed with Docker and I want to automate the whole process by which I start the application.

The whole starting process involves (on Windows):

1. open cmd prompt
2. enter `docker exec -it container_name bash`
3. inside the container, run `python main.py`

Is there a way to create a bash script to run these 3 commands and keep the container window open so I can see the API logs (and run other commands)?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to run the container in the background and retrieve the logs with `docker logs`.

Comment: @Camelid i updated the post becouse i need to run other commands inside container (i am aware  of the philosopy with the containers, one container should do one single  thing)

Comment: You should be able to just make your image's primary command be `CMD python main.py`; you shouldn't need to `docker exec` into containers in normal operation.  What's the other thing you want to do inside the same container?

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker run -it container_name python:3 python main.py
```

Comment: the window doesn't remain open.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
docker exec -it container_name bash -c 'python main.py; read -p"Enter to close window"'
```